# Do shrines recharge?

Tags: diablo-iii

Can I come back to a used shrine later and reuse it?  Healing wells seem to recharge after a couple minutes but shrines either take longer or simply never do.

Answer (score 6):

Aside from entering a new world to generate new shrines they appear to be a single use item as in previous Diablo games (this is based on wandering around areas for roughly 1hour). The exception is the health well, as you already mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I tried testing it, and it seems that they don't recharge. I can't guarantee it, but I waited for 5 minutes, standing next to it, and it wasn't recharged. Then I entered another area and came back, and it still wasn't recharged. I then walked around the map to get as far away from it as possible, came back, and it still wasn't recharged.

Comment: The shrines are not all in the same location and just changing types. You just got lucky with that. Otherwise there should be a shrine between the two crypts in act one on the right side of the graveyard, and I have only seen that one once out of quite a few runs through there (dozen or so).